# cv::Mat external data not being modified after using cv::imdecode

Tags: c++, opencv

edit: In trying to give a straight forward example of the problem it appears I left out what was causing the real issue. I have  modified the example to illustrate the problem.

I am trying to use opencv to perform operations on a `cv::Mat` that is composed of external data.

Consider this example:

```
unsigned char *extern_data = new unsigned char[1280*720*3];
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(1280, 720, CV_8UC3, extern_data); //Create cv::Mat external

//Edit - Added cv::imdecode
mat = cv::imdecode(mat,1);

//In real implementation it would be mat = cv::imdecode(image,'1')
// where image is a cv::Mat of an image stored in a mmap buffer

mat.data[100] = 99;

std::cout << "External array: " << static_cast<int>(extern_data[100]) << std::endl;
std::cout << "cv::Mat array: " << static_cast<int>(mat.data[100]) << std::endl;
```

The result of this is:

```
> External array: 0
> cv::Mat array: 100
```

It is clear this external array is not being modified, therefore new memory is being allocated for the `cv::Mat` array. From my understanding this was not suppose to happen! This should have caused no copy operation, and mat.data should be a pointer to `extern_data[0]`.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: i get 99 for both, with both opencv2.4.2 and 3.0

Comment: It appears I left out a key step. See above.

Comment: It should be `mat = cv::imdecode(mat,1);`

Comment: You are correct, transcription error. Has been corrected. Problem still stands.

Comment: well, now, `mat = cv::imdecode(mat,1);`  is an assignment, that will overwrite *all* of the previous data. what are you trying to achieve now ?

Comment: I see. That is unfortunate. I have a `cv::Mat` that has data that is a mmap from a camera. This data needs to be decoded from MJPEG to BGR. I have done this using `cv::imdecode`. What I would like is for this `cv::imdecode` to transfer data directly into `extern_data`. As a workaround for the moment I am just calling `std::copy()` to fill `extern_data` from a temporary `cv::Mat` that is filled using `cv::imdecode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the way I have got my program to work is to use std::copy. I am still wondering if there is a way to assign the result of cv::imdecode() directly to the external data.

Currently I am using

```
unsigned char *extern_data = new unsigned char[1280*720*3];
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(1280, 720, CV_8UC3, extern_data); //Create cv::Mat external

mat = cv::imdecode(mat,1);

std::copy(mat.data, mat.data + 1280*720*3, extern_data);
```

I just wish i could figure out how to assign the result of `cv::imdecode()` directly to `extern_data` without the additional `std::copy` line!